# Erasing from std vector with size_type index results in compiler error?

Tags: c++, iterator

```
// second try: correct but potentially slow
vector<Student_info> extract_fails(vector<Student_info>& students)
{
    vector<Student_info> fail;
    vector<Student_info>::size_type i = 0;

    // invariant:elements [0, i) of students represent passing grades 
    while (i != students.size())
    { 
        if (fgrade(students[i]))
        {
            fail.push_back(students[i]};
            students.erase(students.begin() + i);
        } else
            ++i;
    }
    return fail;
}
```

The code above comes from the book "Accelerated C++" and will calculate user marks. Based on a failing or passing grade, the result is put into a `fail` vector for students that fail. `students` is the vector that contains student who will pass

All is fine and well, however when I change the following line from

```
students.erase(students.begin() + i);
```

to

```
students.erase(i);
```

I get the following compiler error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector, std::allocator>::erase(size_t&)'

Even though I think they are functionally the same. Could anyone explain what causes this?

Comment: The title of your question is awful. Couldn't you think of anything better for a title?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is the question (in a single sentence)?

Comment: With "Accelerated C++", I guess you mean [this](http://www.acceleratedcpp.com/) book?

Comment: "then, why does program will not compiled when I mess with the code a little on the line 13 into students.erase(i) ?!" .... So you get a compiler error? If so, always include the error you get.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that your question simply is:--- "The code above works fine. However when I change the line from `students.erase(students.begin() + i);` to `students.erase(i);` (which I think are similar) it no longer works. Why is this?" --- If that is your question, then ask that. Don't add all the fluff. :)

Comment: Joachim Pileborg, yes that book...
@Bart, well, my grammar not that good, I think I just try to hard to form a sentence so that people would understood it, but it seems to be happen otherwise.. Dx btw, that's my question :-)

Comment: The answer is a pretty simple one and actually given by the error message you posted. ;)

Comment: I have reformulated your question narrowing it down to what you intended to ask. If I have made any mistake, feel free to correct it.

Comment: well, did you trying to say to me I should create another question to know the definition of "no matching function for call"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "no matching function for call" basically says it all. There is no such erase function which takes a "size_t" as an argument. And that is the whole reason for the perhaps seemingly strange `students.erase(students.begin() + i);` in the first place.

Comment: understood, but what type of arguments that erase function will take then?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I had assumed you understood that part. It [takes an iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/). And an iterator is exactly what `begin()` will return. In addition, you [can increment iterators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/) still resulting in an iterator, which is why the original code works.

Comment: completely understood... ^^

whatsoever, thnx for your commitment for trying to stand my jerk behaviour and my lack of taking time to plan on how to ask(duh, I think I should learn on how to ask too, rather than just learn how to code, lol) anyway, tyvm for everything(edit title, comment, answering etc) ^o^...

Comment: Great. No problem. Just keep your questions small, simple and relevant. Then you'll find people are more than happy to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should you iterator to move through the vector. So you can call iterator = students.erase(it), and it will give you the correct iterator to continue without problem.
Something like this 
`for( vector<Student_info>::itreator it; = students.begin(), it != students.end(); it++)
{
    if(fgrade(*it))
    {
        fail.push_back(*it);
        it = students.erase(it);
    }
}`